# Collatz conjecture : Is that the reason why 3x+1 forms loop with some seeds?

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, collatz-conjecture

Lets start with a negative number: -7

$$
-7\times3+1=-20\\
-20\div2=-10\\
-10\div2=-5\\
-5\times3+1=-14\\
-14\div2=-7
$$

we can sum up these steps as the following functions:

$$
-7\times3+1=-20\\
{-7\times3+1\over2^2}=-5\\
{-7\times3^2+3-2^2\over2^2}=-14\\
{-7\times3^2+3-2^2\over2^3}=-7\\
$$
$$
f_1(x)={x\times3^2+3-2^2\over2^3}\\
$$

$$
{-7\times3^4+3^3+3^2\times2^2+3\times2^3+2^5\over2^6}=-7\\
$$
$$
f_2(x)={x\times3^4+3^3+3^2\times2^2+3\times2^3+2^5\over2^6}\\
$$

Where $f_1(x)$ is the function that sum up the steps: $-7\to-20\to-10\to-5\to-14\to-7$ and $f_2(x)$ is the function that sum up the steps: $-7\to-20\to-10\to-5\to-14\to-7\to-20\to-10\to-5\to-14\to-7$

And:

$$
{\lim_{x \to \infty} f_1(x)\over\lim_{x \to \infty} f_2(x) }=
{-5\times3\over-5\times3+1}\times{-7\times3\over-7\times3+1}=
8/9
$$

Remarks: -5 and -7 are the odd number in the sequence: $-7\to-20\to-10\to-5\to-14\to-7$

In the same way, if we let $x$=-25

$$
{-25\times3^7+3^6+3^5\times2+3^4\times2^2+3^3\times2^4+3^2\times2^5+3\times2^6+2^{10}\over2^{11}}=-25\\
$$

$$
{-25\times3^{14}+3^{13}+3^{12}\times2+3^{11}\times2^2+3^{10}x2^4+3^9\times2^5+3^8\times2^6+3^7\times2^{10}+3^6\times2^{11}+3^5\times2^{12}+3^4\times2^{13}+3^3\times2^{15}+3^2\times2^{16}+3\times2^{17}+2^{21}\over2^{22}}=-25\\
$$
$$
f_3(x)={x\times3^7+3^6+3^5\times2+3^4\times2^2+3^3\times2^4+3^2\times2^5+3\times2^6+2^{10}\over2^{11}}\\
$$

$$
f_4(x)={x\times3^{14}+3^{13}+3^{12}\times2+3^{11}\times2^2+3^{10}x2^4+3^9\times2^5+3^8\times2^6+3^7\times2^{10}+3^6\times2^{11}+3^5\times2^{12}+3^4\times2^{13}+3^3\times2^{15}+3^2\times2^{16}+3\times2^{17}+2^{21}\over2^{22}}\\
$$

Then

$$
{\lim_{x \to \infty} f_3(x)\over\lim_{x \to \infty} f_4(x) }=
{-17\times3\over-17\times3+1}\times
{-25\times3\over-25\times3+1}\times
{-37\times3\over-37\times3+1}\times
{-55\times3\over-55\times3+1}\times
{-41\times3\over-41\times3+1}\times
{-61\times3\over-61\times3+1}\times
{-91\times3\over-91\times3+1}=
2187/2048
$$

And as Collatz conecture restricts to positive numbers:

$$
{1\times3+1\over2^2}=1\\
$$
$$
f_5(x)={x\times3+1\over2^2}\\
$$
$$
{1\times3^2+3+2^2\over2^4}=1\\
$$
$$
f_6(x)={x\times3^2+3+2^2\over2^4}\\
$$

And:

$$
{\lim_{x \to \infty} f_5(x)\over\lim_{x \to \infty} f_6(x) }=
{1\times3\over1\times3+1}=
3/4
$$

Can we say that in the function
$f(n) =
\begin{cases}
n/2,  & \text{if $n$ is even} \\
3n+1, & \text{if $n$ is odd}
\end{cases}$
a loop occurs if:

$$
{\lim_{x \to \infty} f_1(x)\over\lim_{x \to \infty} f_2(x) }=
{a_1\times3\over a_1\times3+1}\times{a_2\times3\over a_2\times3+1}\times...{a_n\times3\over a_n\times3+1}
$$

Comment: Please use subscripts by typing `a_n` for $a_n$ (for example), and use curly braces like `a_{12}` for $a_{12}$ if there is more than one symbol in the subscript.

Comment: Starting with a negative number is in essence creating a distinct function which would be regarded as a $3n-1$ step (as opposed to a $3n+1$ step) for positive seeds.

Comment: @KeithBackman, actually I tested this in anothers functions like: $-3n+1$, $-3n-1$ and $5n+1$. But I haven't tested yet in this function: $f(n) =
\begin{cases}
n/3,  & \text{if $n \pmod 3 = 0$} \\
2n+1, & \text{if $n \pmod 3 = 1$}\\
2n-1, & \text{if $n \pmod 3 = 2$}
\end{cases}$

Comment: @Keith Backman, It's not unusual to consider negative starting values as one way of generalizing the Colaltz function. Indeed, extending its domain to all rational numbers (positive and negative) with odd denominators has led to insights about structures of cycles. Some even like to extend the domain to all 2-adic integers. I'd say this is a valid way to study the problem.

Comment: OP, the numbers that you're recovering in these limit calculations are descriptions of the cycle shapes. With the –7 cycle, you get a fraction involving $2^3$, because the cycle has 3 even numbers in it, and $3^2$, because the cycle has 2 odd numbers in it. Similarly, the cycle on –17 has 11 even numbers and 7 odds, so you have in your fraction $2^{11}$ and $3^7$. Similarly also for the famous cycle on positive 1.